# Call get_template_part() custom permalink

Tags: php, get-template-part

How to call `get_template_part()` with custom permalink, I use childTheme from twentytwelve. In my theme I want to call popular post with `get_template_part()`.

ex.
If I call link http: //domain.com/popular
I want to show file `popular.php` (location: childtheme-name/popular.php)

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping of URL directly to a template file you describe (mapping URL to a file) is quite rare technique in WordPress, sometimes called *static pages*.

It is rare because in general that's not how WordPress works. It works by mapping URL to query variables to WP_Query to template hierarchy to template file. Going from URL to a file skips a lot of mandatory steps.

The low key implementation would be to create a page and make your file a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/) for it.

The more direct implementation is also possible, but you would have to both build a custom rewrite rule and implement processing it from scratch.